# The type or namespace name 'MIDI' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I have a midi.dll, where do I install the file with Monodevelop IDE?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a .NET dll you need to add a reference, look at the [Referencing our library part of the documentation](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Creating_A_Simple_Solution) to see with screen shots an all how to add the reference. You should find it on the ".NET Assembly" tab.